# Gitlab CI/CD is running manual job automatically after dependencies/needs job fails

Tags: gitlab-ci

Company policy is to run a container vulnerability scan before we deploy updates. So our pipeline runs the scan, then has a manual step to deploy the container to OpenShift.

The problem is if the scan job fails, the deploy step runs automatically even if other jobs in between are skipped.

```
#scan job, 
aqua:dev:
  extends: .scan
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master"'
      allow_failure: false
  retry: 2
  needs:
    - docker:dev

#blocker step I added just for testing, this gets skipped when previous job fails
blocker:dev:
  extends: .blocker
  needs:
    - aqua:dev
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "DEV"

#Deployment step, runs despite needs/dependencies jobs failing
openshift:sbx:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "DEV"
      when: manual
  retry: 2
  needs:
    - aqua:dev
    - blocker:dev
  dependencies:
    - aqua:dev
    - blocker:dev
```

[image]

I've tried just about everything I can think of (or Google) to get the manual job to stop. allow_failure:false just about everywhere, adding dependencies instead of just needs, etc.

All the documentation I can find leads me to believe that just defining needs should be enough... so what am I missing?

EDIT: A week after I posted this our company upgraded our GitLab version from 14.4.1 to 14.9.5 and it now seems to be working as I had expected. So most likely this was a bug in 14.4.1 or the feature was changed somehow since.

Comment: Can you provide a complete reproducible example? Or edit your question to include the keys (e.g., `.blocker`, `.scan`) with which you are extending in these definitions?

Answer (score 0):

If Your `blocker:dev:` job inherits `when: manual` from `.blocker`, it will also need `allow_failure: false` to actually block jobs.

If `allow_failure:` is `true` (which is implied if `when: manual` is set) then job failure (or skipping) won't block subsequent jobs from running.